# Why is the PHPMyAdmin login page showing a bunch of crazy text, not the user login/password field?

Tags: php

I've never experienced this before.

I do have PHP installed.

This is a sample, a portion of the top set of text

```
addJSON( 'list', PMA_RecentFavoriteTable::getInstance('recent')->getHtmlList() ); exit; } if ($GLOBALS['PMA_Config']->isGitRevision()) { if (isset($_REQUEST['git_revision']) && $GLOBALS['is_ajax_request'] == true) { PMA_printGitRevision(); exit; } echo '
```

Recently there has been this change of /var/www/html being the public directory, I'm not sure if that matters. I do have php installed, it looks like php is not being parsed above.

I checked my apache2.conf and I did not see anything regarding module php or mime type...

What do you think is wrong?

Comment: Exactly, PHP is no longer parsed on your server. Questions about server issues (web server configuration, "404 - Not Found" error, etc), should be asked on serverfault.com.

Comment: yeah I missed libapache2-mod-php5 thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP doesnt work, you just get the "source" file instead of it executing

Not that it has any relevance to programming problems, but i would try a simple hello world echo script on the same folder just to be sure it is server issue and not phpmyamdin one

Answer (score 2):

Changing of public directory has affected your apache config or php.ini.   You should revert it back and check it once again.

Comment: I didn't do it on purpose, it seems to be a new standard now

Comment: Check the file has php open tag and is it missing any syntax. I guess its partially showing the code snippet.  So it may be syntax issue

Comment: This is default phpmyadmin code I didn't modify it, the problem has already been solved by installing libapache2-mod-php5

Answer (score 0):

add this to apapche2.conf

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        php_flag engine on
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```